# Get labels from fields ordered on block plugin - Drupal 8

Tags: views, 8, blocks, plugins

I'm trying to create a block with a label list using all labels of a specific field type, entity_reference_revisions.

I created a Block plugin and load the EntityTypeManager service.
I tried:

```
    $values = array(
      'targetEntityType' => 'node',
      'bundle' => $bundle,
      'mode' => $view_mode,
      'status' => TRUE,
    );
    $entity_view_display = $this->entityType->getStorage('entity_view_display')->create($values);
    $fields = $entity_view_display->get('fieldDefinitions');
    $labels = [];
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
      if($field->getFieldStorageDefinition()->getType() == 'entity_reference_revisions') {
        $labels[] = $field->get('label');
      }
    }
```

The problem is that I get the fields in a wrong order, and I can't get the weight attribute.

Comment: The weight is configured in the viewmode, not in the field definition, try `$entity_view_display->getComponents()`. BTW you know you create a viewmode instead of loading an existing one in the first line and so only get default values?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it loading the field definition using entityManager, I got the weight attribute, and then ordered the labels by weight.

```
$node = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->get('node');
$bundle = $node->getType();
$view_mode = 'full';

$fields = [];
foreach($this->entityManager->getFieldDefinitions('node', $bundle)  as $field_name => $field_definition) {
  if($field_definition->getType() == 'entity_reference_revisions') {
    $field_name = $field_definition->getName();
    $element = $node->$field_name->view($view_mode);
    $fields[] = [
      'name' => $field_name,
      'label' => $field_definition->getLabel(),
      'weight' => $element['#weight'],
    ];

  }
}

usort($fields, [$this, 'sortByWeight']);
```